# React Typescript map loop interface error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, loops

I am trying to interface a map loop in JavaScript, what I have done is:

```
interface RoutesType {
  path: string;
  name: string;
  icon: string;
  layout: string;
}
```

the code of the map loop is:

```
// creates the links that appear in the left menu / Sidebar
  const createLinks = (routes: object[]) => {
    return routes.map((prop: RoutesType, key: number) => {
      return (
        <NavItem key={key}>
          <NavLink to={prop.layout + prop.path} tag={NavLinkRRD} onClick={closeCollapse} activeClassName="active">
            <i className={prop.icon} />
            {prop.name}
          </NavLink>
        </NavItem>
      );
    });
  };
```

The error I cannot understand is the following

```
TypeScript error: Argument of type '(prop: RoutesType, key: number) => Element' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: object, index: number, array: object[]) => Element'.
  Types of parameters 'prop' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'RoutesType': path, name, icon, layout
```

Could you help me understand this issue?
Thanks,
F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this error is that the `routes` argument of type `object[]` cannot be cast to a type of `RoutesType[]`.

The reason that TypeScript is attempting this type-cast is that type of `routes` is inferred and expected to be `RoutesType[]`, due to the type of the `prop` argument on the map callback.

A fix would be to revise your `createLinks` function signature like this:

```
 /* Update routes to RoutesType[] */
 const createLinks = (routes: RoutesType[]) => {
    return routes.map((prop: RoutesType, key: number) => {
      return (
        <NavItem key={key}>
          <NavLink to={prop.layout + prop.path} tag={NavLinkRRD} 
                   onClick={closeCollapse} activeClassName="active">
            <i className={prop.icon} />
            {prop.name}
          </NavLink>
        </NavItem>
      );
    });
  };
```

This change will require that all calls to `createLink` throughout your project specficy a `routes` value that is strictly typed to `RoutesType[]`